# Is there any other way to display image without getting undefined onclick which is already rendered as template to html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, undefined-reference

I am cretaing a small project related to managing books using db.json file as database. This is some of the code relevant to the actual problem

index.html

```
<body>
  <ul class="books-container"></ul>
  <img src="" id="fullImage">
</body>
```

db.js

```
const container = document.querySelector('books-container')

const renderBooks = async () => {
    let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/books'

    const res = await fetch(uri)
    const books = await res.json()
    
    let template = '';
    books.forEach(book => {
        template += `
                <li class="books">
                    <img class="image" src="${book.image}" alt="${book.title}" data-image="${book.image}" width="80px" height="115px">
                    <h6 class="title">${book.title}</h6>
                </li>
        `
    })
    container.innerHTML = template
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => renderBooks())

window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target.className == 'image') {
        let imageUrl = e.target.dataset.image
        document.getElementById('fullImage').setAttribute('src', imageUrl)
    }
})
```

Here am rendering image as thumbnail and title to the html page as template. I want to display full image as modal when clicked on thumbnail so I have taken image reference and displaying full image based on click event. It's working fine and displaying the full image but when I click on that full image it disappears and gives me "undefined" value. Is there any other way to display that full image without getting undefined on click ?

Thank you

Comment: try consoling in click listener like console.log(e.target)

Comment: @dinesh oz -> By consoling event listener only I got reference details of image and dataset. that isn't the problem. When I click on thumbnail image it displays the Full Image everything is fine to this point. but when i click anywhere on that particular full image it disappears and gives me "undefined". Why is that ?